# How standard settings suppose to be in build.gradle if use Cucumber JVM and Allure?

Tags: java, gradle, cucumber, allure

I'm able to run Cucumber JVM with Gradle but not sure what exactly I need to add in build.gradle to get Allure report after test execution.
I checked an official website and read section Cucumber JVM but there is information only about maven project [cucumber jvm|https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_cucumber_jvm].
Could anybody give an example with the appropriate setting for build.gradle file if we use the combination of Cucumber JVM + Gradle + Allure.

Comment: Please provide some example on what you tried, so that we can help you. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm trying to find basic configuration example for build.gradle when using Cucumber JVM and Allure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

1. Add task Cucumber as recommended here (https://cucumber.io/docs/tools/java/#gradle)

   - Add the following in args for task cucumber

```
args = [ '--plugin', 'io.qameta.allure.cucumber4jvm.AllureCucumber4Jvm', '--glue', 'path_to_your_glue_code', ("path_to_your_feature")]
```

- Add dependency for the plugin

```
dependencies { testCompile("io.qameta.allure:allure-cucumber4-jvm:2.10.0") }
```

2. Add allure plugin (https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.qameta.allure)
3. From the command line `gradle cucumber` and allure-reports directory will be generated in your root project.
4. The final step to generate html report

```
allure generate 'path_to_allure_results_folder' -c -o 'path_to_your_report_folder\'
```